# Checking permanent online Status

Tags: android, connection

I check if the Phone have a Internetconnection with this code:

```
online = SystemCheckInternetConn.getInstance(this).isOnline(this);
```

How can I continuously check if the phone has a connection or not?

Comment: what do you mean "check permanent if the phone have a connection or not?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register a broadcastreceiver to listen to changes in connection. Try something like this:

```
registerReceiver(MyNetworkStateReceiver, new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));

private BroadcastReceiver NetworkStateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            boolean haveConnection = haveNetworkConnection(context);
        }

        private boolean haveNetworkConnection(Context context) {
            boolean haveConnectedWifi = false;
            boolean haveConnectedMobile = false;

            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
            for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) {
                if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
                    if (ni.isConnected())
                        haveConnectedWifi = true;
                if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
                    if (ni.isConnected())
                        haveConnectedMobile = true;
            }
            return haveConnectedWifi || haveConnectedMobile;
        }
    };
```

Then do something with this newfound knowledge :)